# How to disable Maximize button in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I am using opencv-python or cv2 to access the mobile camera.
The thing is that how to disable the maximize button in it for windows.
You may give me an idea what to do my current code is-

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
print('Install Ip Ip Webcam in Play store and click on start server.NOTE: connect the mobile to the same wifi as the pc')
url = (f"{source}/shot.jpg")
while True:
    img_resp = requests.get(url)
    img_arr = np.array(bytearray(img_resp.content), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, -1)
    img = imutils.resize(img, width=1000, height=1800)
    cv2.imshow("Mobi-CCTV", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i have tried many online but none work
Please update this code and help me out with this

Comment: may be **possible** using system-specific APIs. what OS are you on? -- your code contains a lot of irrelevant stuff. please review [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Just googling by "How to disable Maximize button in opencv-python" gives the [answer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/31177/disable-maximize-button-for-displayed-image-window/).

Not possible in OpenCV. The interface is more for debugging purposes. If you need the possibility to adapt GUI interfaces use a language designed for that like Qt.

The only idea is to check window size with:

```
cv2.getWindowImageRect('WindowName')
```

And if the size of window changes, then minimize it:

```
Minimize = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(Minimize, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)
```

Comment: i am on windows 11